# Crop an android canvas drawArc

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I try to create a custom widget and I have problem.
I create an half circle with `canvas.drawArc` for create this:

[image: Crop the circle]

but the size of my widget is the square of arc.

Is it possible to crop widget size to take only the size of my half circle?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem  :

the call of setMeasuredDimension()  is with bad dimension.